# When I tap on GridView Item, I want to show some pop up like thing containing images and text... How to show it?

Tags: android

- this pop up should bottom aligned and comes when I tap on any grid item and in the form of columns... like for 5 images first row should show 3 images and second row should show two..
- I have tried with alert dialog, but it is coming in list view ...
- i am trying with split action bar but it may contain only system images..
- I have tried all possible things. but i am unable to get solution..
  please help me...
- Does any one know how to do that??????

Comment: check below library.[twowaygridview](http://androidcustomviews.com/portfolio/two-way-gridview/),And [STAGGEREDGRIDVIEW](http://androidcustomviews.com/portfolio/staggeredgridview-by-maurycy-wojtowicz/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a touch listener to the grid view - `setOnTouchListener`.
Override method `onTouch` and implement your logic to show/hide the popup.

Remember a popup could also be a layout in your view for which you change the visibility from `GONE` to `VISIBLE` and viceversa. To have a better result do that with an animation (maybe fade + translate).